# SSIS Cache Lookup fails with invalid file name error

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs fine in Visual Studio, but when deployed to the server it fails with this error message:

Code: 0xC020930A     Source: Data Flow Task Lookup [2951]     Description: The cache file name is either not provided or is not valid. Provide a valid cache file name.  End Error

Why might this error occur? I can find little documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this error can occur when Permissions for the SQL Server Agent are not set up correctly for the location of the file used in the lookup function. It is a corollary error to the "Invalid File Path" error that can occur with excel/flat file connections when the folder permissions are not correct.